# Should names of scientific theories be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, science

I'd really like to safely write stuff like *Special Relativity*, *Quantum Mechanics*, *Theory of Evolution* without capitals; but I don't want to regret it, whence my question.

Should the name of scientific theories be written with capitals?

Comment: What do you find in English writing that you admire?  Why not do the same?

Comment: I just would like to have a criterion. Why doesn't one write `Homology Theory` with capitals? They're proper nouns as well.

Comment: Well, I dare say that some authors might. Where you draw the line between an "ordinary" noun phrase and something that merits capitals is essentially a matter of personal/editorial judgement.

Comment: Ogden's Basic English is not identical to Ogden's basic English.

Comment: I agree with Neil Coffey, there is no definitive answer, it's just personal preference.

Comment: Did you mean "hence my question", rather than "whence my question"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many theories of evolution; but one is so well known that *the Theory of Evolution* will be assumed to refer to Darwin's. *Quantum mechanics*, on the other hand, is a field of study, and doesn't need capitalization any more than *physics* does.

Comment: Although... one might actually in some cases capitalise "Physics".

Comment: @NeilCoffey Sure, if it's the first word of a sentence, or if a sadistic parent names their child Physics :-)