# Should "Creationism" or "creationism" be used in a scientific writing?

Tags: word-choice, capitalization

I'm editing a scientific article, and the word "creationism" is used a few times—lowercase and uppercase spellings are both utilized. I have no clue whether to use the lowercase or uppercase spellings consistently.

Here are the instances where the word is used:

> The ongoing debate of evolution versus creationism is not a new issue.
>
> Evolution’s beliefs follow a scientific line of thought and do not classify as religious beliefs, unlike a notion such as Creationism.
>
> This debate created many sparks, with some scientists condemning Nye for agreeing to such a debate. They state that it gives Creationism an air of credibility that it does not deserve.
>
> Nevertheless, wherever the debate might turn next, the general consensus is evolution is based on science and Creationism is based on faith—both equally indispensable components of today’s society.

Any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you capitalizing *evolution*?

Comment: No. To be honest, I've never seen evolution capitalized in any piece of literature, except in the front of a sentence or in a title.

Comment: Perhaps you might looks at [Should names of scientific theories be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/91735/31489).  I would say if you're going to capitalize creationism then you should capitalize the names of the various scientific theories you also refer to.  But, usually, I wouldn't capitalize a scientific theory.  I'd just say, "the theory of evolution."  I would say that people capitalize creationism to give it an air of authority as an equal to scientific theories.  As a scientific reader, seeing creationism capitalized rankles me.  So, keep in mind who your audience is.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make this word lowercase. And same, I shudder when I see creationism capitalized!

Comment: It depends on whether it's viewed as a philosophical viewpoint or a religion.  In most cases Creationism is a religion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the article is scientific, then creationism is not a proper noun in that genre. If the article were to be aimed at a religious audience, then capitalization might be warranted.

Comment: Thanks, you're amazing. I don't know why I didn't think of this. :D

Comment: Just here to help.